# angular navigation router in observable can't work

Tags: angular

I have un button in my home file html component and the click in this button doesn't work when i call router.navigate['path'].

When i clicked in picture button, i redirect to the correct  good path after the page is reloaded and i return to localhost:4200.

Anyone can i help me ?

```
enter code here
<pre>
const routes: Routes = [
         { path: "", component: HomeComponent },
         { path: "home", component: HomeComponent },
         { path: "firstcomponent", component: FirstComponent },
         { path: "secondcomponent", component: SecondComponent },
         { path: "**", component: PagenotfoundComponent }
  ];
<ng-container *ngFor="let cat of category; let index=index">
  <div>
   <a href="#" (click)="detailCategorie(cat.id)" >
      <img [src]="cat.url"
      [alt]="cat.nom" [title]='cat.nom' />
   </a>
  </div>
</ng-container>
detailCategorie(id:number){

   this.service.getCategorie(id).subscribe(data=>{
    this.categorie = data;

 let nomCategorie : string = this.categorie.nom;


switch (nomCategorie) {
case 'first':
    this.router.navigate(["/firstcomponent"]);
    break;
case 'second':
    this.router.navigate(["/secondcomponent"]);
    break;
default:
    console.log("No categorie exists!");
    break;
}

 },err=>{
    console.log("Erreur retourne categorie choisie : ",err);
 });
```

}

Comment: Are you sure the `getCategorie` emits a value on subscribe?

Comment: yes @Krujit getCategorie emits a value to subscribe

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove **href="#"** from the link. My solution is:

```
<a (click)="detailCategorie(cat.id)" >
  <img [src]="cat.url"
  [alt]="cat.nom" [title]='cat.nom' />
```